# inserting the values of a datagridview on the database

Tags: c#, database, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I've created a datagridview which is binded to a datatable. How would I add all of the contents in my datatable to the database with 1 buttonclick? for ex: I have inserted 5 values in my datatable. How would I insert all of the 5 datatable at once?

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet sir. Because I only know how to add data one by one.

Comment: What does "How would I insert all of the 5 datatable at once" mean? Have you 5 DataTables or 5 records in one DataTable? Btw, if you know how to insert one records, you also know how to insert all rows of a DataTable one by one. You should use a DataAdapter to Update the whole DataTable: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: @Tim Schmelter 5 or Multple records in the datable. Sir I only know the insert into command. Can I have multiple insert commands with a single button click? And I don't know how to access the data of each row of the datatable.

Comment: I just want that the temporary data i stored in the datatable will be transferred into my database with a single button click

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```
string ConnString= "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True;Pooling=False";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for(int i=0; i< dataGridView1.Rows.Count;i++)
    {
        string StrQuery= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +", " + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +");";

      try
      {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(StrQuery, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
      }
    }
}
```

the ConnectionString you can get it from the property of you DB, also put " ' " in the Command when you want to insert value which is not number...

Comment: I assume this code will work irrespective of if the DGV is bound to the database table or not? If I wanted to truncate the table before inserting the items I could just `ExecuteNonQuery` using a different string `"TRUNCATE TABLE ...."` ?