# Inserting data from a DataGridView to a database

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a small DataGridView which lets the user enter data.

[image: Ths is the grid]

And I'm trying this code to enter the data in the DataGridView to the database.

```
    strQry = "INSERT INTO Emp_Fam_Details (empID, famName, famAge, famRelation, famOccup)" _
            & "VALUES (@ID, @Name, @Age, @Rel, @Occ)"
    Dim adapFam As New SqlDataAdapter
    adapFam.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(strQry, sqlcon)

    For i As Integer = 0 To grdFamily.Rows.Count - 1
        adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", txtEmpID.Text.Trim)
        adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", grdFamily.Columns(0))
        adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", grdFamily.Columns(1))
        adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rel", grdFamily.Columns(2))
        adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Occ", grdFamily.Columns(3))

        result2 = adapFam.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Next
```

When I run this, I come across this error.

[image: This is the error]

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9391411/1077789) solution here on SO but since I'm using Parameters not appended values, I'm having a hard time understanding how to do it with parameters.

Can anyone please show me how to do this?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot map **columns to data**. What you need to add is the row cell data of that column index

This is wrong `grdFamily.Columns(0)`

Parameter assignment within the for loop should be corrected as follows

**NOTE** Please change datatype as per your table.

```
adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Age", SqlDbType.VarChar)
adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Rel", SqlDbType.VarChar)
adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Occ", SqlDbType.VarChar)

For i As Integer = 0 To grdFamily.Rows.Count - 1
  adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters[0].Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtEmpID.Text.Trim)
  adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters[1].Value = grdFamily.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value
  adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters[2].Value = grdFamily.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value
  adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters[3].Value = grdFamily.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value
  adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters[4].Value = grdFamily.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value

    result2 = adapFam.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
```

Comment: this works great. Thanks you very much. Although I'm facing a little problem here. When I run it, the first row gets inserted fine but when it comes to insert the second row it throws [this](http://i41.tinypic.com/5zgriu.png) error. Is there like a way to _refresh_ the parameters or something?

Comment: Well, you are adding the parameters inside the loop. That means you are adding parameters for every i. Please add parameters before the loop and assign values inside the loop. It should work...

Comment: I used `adapFam.InsertCommand.Parameters.Clear()` after `ExecuteNonQuery`. It works fine now. Thank you for your help.