# how to save records inputted in datagrid to sql database

Tags: sql, vb.net, datagrid, visual-studio-2003

my system concept is this. im done displaying columns from different tables using inner join.

im finding a hard time because, i think that you can only use insert command in sql to one table at a time.

but my datagrid displays different columns called from different table.

how would be the structure of my sql syntax be? and also calling the stored procedure on vb.net 2003

thanks any ideas anyone

THIS IS MY SQL STORED PROC

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddToOfficeEquipmentProfile AS

INSERT INTO dbo.tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_ID
                                        , Report_ID
                                        , OE_Category
                                        , OE_SubCategory
                                        , OE_Name
                                        , OE_User
                                        , OE_Brand
                                        , OE_Model
                                        , OE_Specs
                                        , OE_SerialNo
                                        , OE_PropertyNo
                                        , OE_Static_IP
                                        , OE_Vendor
                                        , OE_PurchaseDate
                                        , OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear
                                        , OE_WarrantyStatus
                                        , OE_Status
                                        , OE_Dept_Code
                                        , OE_Location_Code
                                        , OE_Remarks)
VALUES
  (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)
GO
```

THIS IS MY VB CODE

```
Dim sqlconn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    sqlconn.ConnectionString = "server = SKPI-APPS1;" & _
    "Database = EOEMS;integrated security=true"

    Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand
    Command.Connection = sqlconn
    Command.CommandText = "AddToOfficeEquipmentProfile"
    Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    Dim sAdapter As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(Command)
    Dim DataSet As DataSet = New DataSet(Command.CommandText)

    sAdapter.Fill(DataSet)
    DataGrid1.DataSource = DataSet.Tables(0)
    MsgBox(MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly, "YOU HAVE SUCCESSFULLY ADDED RECORDS TO THE TABLE")
```

it returns error pointing to

```
 sAdapter.Fill(DataSet)
```

HERE IS MY SECOND CODE BELOW WITH NO STORED PROCEDURE NEEDED

```
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim sql As String


    sql = "INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_ID, Report_ID, OE_Category, OE_SubCategory, OE_Name, OE_User, OE_Brand, OE_Model, OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo, OE_PropertyNo, OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus, OE_Status, OE_Dept_Code, OE_Location_Code, OE_Remarks)VALUES(DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)"
    Try
        sqlconn.Open()
        adapter.InsertCommand = New SqlCommand(sql, sqlconn)
        adapter.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox("Row inserted !! ")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

but still not working

Comment: @joshua

[code] INSERT INTO Persons
VALUES (4,'Nilsen', 'Johan', 'Bakken 2', 'Stavanger') [/code]

Comment: please add this in your question, and you are only inserting in only one Table ?

Comment: that is a sample code for inserting records to a table..
but all i know is you can only insert records at one table at a time..

but what i need is to insert in different tables at the same time.
because i called columns in different tables at the same time to display it on a datagrid

Comment: then you just add several INSERT code  then execute it at a time.

Comment: @ArwinZhang sir if it was that easy i wouldnt ask questions at all but thank you for your advice

Comment: @ivandinglasan, It just as easy as what i said. I had tried it by my self before, the code surely will get long depend on what you want. Tried first and said what the error again.

Comment: @ArwinZhang sir here is my codes kindly help me to revise to make it work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is so long, and by what i have mean is..

```
 Try
                    con = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\notifdb.accdb")
                    Dim command As String
                    command = "INSERT INTO NFTB (NOTIF, EMP_NO, EMP_NAME, [POSITION]) VALUES (@NOTIF, @EMP_NO, @EMP_NAME, @POSITION)"
                    con.Open()
                    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
                    cmd = New OleDbCommand(command, con)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NOTIF", NOTIFTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_NO", EMP_NOTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EMP_NAME", EMP_NAMETextBox.Text)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSITION", POSITIONTextBox.Text)
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Catch exceptionObject As Exception
                    MessageBox.Show(exceptionObject.Message)
                Finally
                    con.Close()
                End Try
```

i just said about the insert code, beside that you must do by your self.
And SQL never have DEFAULT value, you must change the value of your column name to some thing, then add parameter to it that what textbox or field in your form that will be input to your database..

Comment: i know that i must do it by myself, im just asking ideas on how to revise it. i mean how will be the code structure be. ill be trying your code sir thanks ill be marking it as correct when it works

Comment: i replaced the cmd = ...... with me sql syntax but.  error is it is underligned by blue line saying value type of 'string' cannot be converted to...

Comment: with " " or even without " " its underligned by blue line..

cmd = "INSERT INTO tblOfficeEquipmentProfile(OE_ID, Report_ID, OE_Category, OE_SubCategory, OE_Name, OE_User, OE_Brand, OE_Model, OE_Specs, OE_SerialNo, OE_PropertyNo, OE_Static_IP, OE_Vendor, OE_PurchaseDate, OE_WarrantyInclusiveYear, OE_WarrantyStatus, OE_Status, OE_Dept_Code, OE_Location_Code, OE_Remarks) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT)"

Comment: why your value got DEFAULT? Also, the value and column, you just write what column do you want to insert, don't need all...

Comment: I dont see anything wrong on insert into myowntable name(column names,... etc...

i think my problem is the default yep your right.. but if not default then, how could i save the data inputted in my datagrid and save it to my sql server?

Comment: Look answer. I have change to save code, you just need to repeat the Insert and parameter vavlue

Comment: im starting to get what you mean sir. last one, its not a textbox field. its a datagrid? 

assuming that this POSITION is in column1 row 1
what code will i put for "POSITIONTextBox.Text"

[code]
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@POSITION", POSITIONTextBox.Text)[/code]

Comment: try to check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784301/inserting-data-from-a-datagridview-to-a-database