# DataGridView to MS Access Database

Tags: c#, ms-access, datagridview, dataadapter

I'm trying to update a database after the changes in a DataGridView.

After changing the code several times, I've come to this one-liner:

```
primeTableAdapter.Update((PrimeDataSet.PrimeDataTable)(primeDataSet.Tables["Prime"]));
```

The method returns the correct number of rows added / edited and entering the form again without closing the entire application everything seems fine. The new rows are kept in the DataGridView. However, the Access file is not changed one bit, so when I relaunch the application they disappear.

I've bound the DataGridView to the table using the "Add New Data Source" wizard and I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

I've also found the code at: [Inserting data from a DataGridView to a database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784301/inserting-data-from-a-datagridview-to-a-database) and it seems similar to what I have to do, but I wasn't able to translate the vb.net code to something that would compile. However, I'm fairly sure it is really, really close to what I have to do.

**Later Edit: I had added the database to the project. By setting the Copy to Output Directory property to Copy if Newer the changes were persistent between sessions.**

Comment: In order to update the Adapter correctly you will need to have the appropriate INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE commands wired up to it. you will also need to ensure that you DatagridView is Bound to the DataTable, so that all chnages you are making in the DGV are reflected to teh underlying datasource.

Comment: The wizard took care of that. The DataGridView is also bound to the DataTable...

Comment: I wouldnt rely on a wizard fro anything if you need to have an understanding of what your doing. Code first, if your new to this.

Comment: I've understood the basics of database communication in C#. It's lots of unnecessary pain compared to Java, in my opinion. However, I am compelled to use C# and this particular wizard for my school project. I'm sure it's faster and easier that the classical method, that's why it is absolutely frustrating that I haven't found any viable solutions until now. I find it very peculiar that the additions are persistent throughout the run of the application and that leads me to believe that the problem isn't the binding, but some access rights on the Database file. Have you ever encountered this?

Comment: What I'm saying is: if the binding definitely was dysfunctional, shouldn't it simply ignore the changes I do in my DGV? They are persistent throughout that session (launch), but they disappear when another session is launched...

Answer (score 1):

if you want to pay,you can use a third party (Spire dataExport ) it make things more easier : to save datagrid into msAccess :

```
private void btnExportToAccess_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport accessExport = new              
        Spire.DataExport.Access.AccessExport();
        accessExport.DataSource = Spire.DataExport.Common.ExportSource.DataTable;
        accessExport.DataTable = this.dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable;
        accessExport.DatabaseName = @"..\..\ToMdb.mdb";
        accessExport.TableName = "ExportFromDatatable";
        accessExport.SaveToFile();
    }
```

and [Here](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.DataExport/Spire.DataExport-Program-Guide/How-to-Export-Data-into-MS-Access-in-C.html) a link where you can find more clarification